# How to set color code of PieChart in ADF 12c?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am fairly new to ADF. I am trying to add a Piechart in my ADF Fusion application. It will contain count of records based on Status. Statuses can be Error, Not processed, Closed, Completed etc. By default ADF is selecting random colors for these status. How can I set fixed colors for each status. Like E(Error) should be Red, N(Not Processed) should be blue etc.

Currently Piechart is showing legend of values which are in the piechart. Not all of it. How to show all of them in the legend?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this--

```
 <dvt:pieChart value="#{chartDataSource.extendedPieData}" var="row" styleClass="AFStretchWidth">
       <dvt:pieDataItem value="#{row.value}"
         color="#{row.status== 'E' ? "#FF0000" : '' }" />
          <dvt:chartLegend rendered="true"/>
         </dvt:pieChart>
```

Refer the below link for detailed code:
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/feature/chart/pieCharts.jspx;jsessionid=VEJ3pX_rMvmCbYrlDJqqVaJ9kLfafUeu8uaAjeRcWmgizc1Cm3Lj!-1820490141

Answer (score 0):

Add the below tag in you pie chart

```
 <dvt:seriesSet>
                    <dvt:series index="0" color="#65C280"/>
                    <dvt:series index="1" color="#1F7CB5"/>
                    <dvt:series index="2" color="#ff9000"/>
                    <dvt:series index="3" color="#c93626"/>
  </dvt:seriesSet>
```

To show all the values in legend , your model (used to render pie chart) should have all the values as rows/columns even if the particular label doesn't have any value in db.

Comment: This will be based on Index not the value. So if I am not getting one of the status, it will rearrange the status color and show the different color to different status.